# R: Change y axis scaling in boxplot

Tags: r

I'm using R to create some boxplots.

Here is my code:

```
fps_error <- c(0.033872847, 0.041710742,0.023839866,0.017763328,0.044510719,0.016390502,0.056766647,0.101326807,0.013990558,0.014848592)
fps_error = fps_error *100
fps_qp_error <-c(1.631578947,  2.263157895, 1.45,   1.2,    2.388888889,    1.05,   1.764705882,    4.642857143,    0.95,   1.047619048)
bit_error <- c(0.113818414,0.17059614,  0.110048539,    0.030207725,    0.157858064,    0.031467476,    0.258009778,    0.220182593,    0,  0.030935528)
bit_error = bit_error *100
bit_qp_error <-c(0.65, 0.80952381,  0.523809524,    0.142857143,    0.904761905,    0.142857143,    1.473684211,    1.047619048,    0,  0.19047619)
ssim_error <-c(0.012973075,  0.006374072,   0.003292312,    0.003139452,    0.009791549,0.008385301,    0.003566528,    0.00986248, 0.003586361,    0.003680912)
ssim_qp_error <-c(3.476190476, 0.944444444, 0.7,    0.65,   2.095238095,    1.470588235,    0.75,   1.529411765,    0.736842105,    0.8)
ssim_qp_error = ssim_qp_error *100

all_errors = cbind(fps_error, bit_error, ssim_error)
modes = cbind(rep("FPS error",10), rep("Bitrate error",10), rep("SSIM error",10))

journal_linear_data <-data.frame(fps_error, fps_qp_error,bit_error,bit_qp_error,ssim_error,ssim_qp_error )

bp = boxplot(all_errors~modes, data=journal_linear_data, main="Percentage error per mode for B2", xlab="Mode", ylab="% error")
```

This is the resulted image.
[image]

I want to change the y axis scale to show fair enough all the boxlots. E.g. for SSIM error I can't see the error.

Comment: You can use `ylim`, but it won't show you all the details you want as youur SSIM error values are too small. The SSIM error variance (compared to the other two) is way too small.

Comment: Just ran your code with ylim=c(-10,30) which increases the scale but as @rbm points out, it isn't what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to have non equal steps in y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
journal_linear_data <-data.frame(fps_error, fps_qp_error,bit_error,bit_qp_error,ssim_error,ssim_qp_error )

yvars <- c("fps_error","bit_error","ssim_error")

graphics.off()

op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 3), #matrix of plots
          oma = c(0,0,3,0))   #outer margins

for (i in 1:3) {boxplot(journal_linear_data[,yvars[i]], xlab=yvars[i], ylab="% error")}

par(op)

mtext(text="Percentage error per mode for B2",side=3, line=1.5, font=2, cex=2, col='black')
```

[See plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IStJY.jpg)

Comment: That's a fair enough solution! Thanks! Is it possible to have the same x and y axis for all graphs?

Comment: In case I want to increase the size of x and y labels, what should I do?

Comment: I found the solution `par(cex.lab=2.5)
par(cex.axis=2.5)` before for loop, but now the y labels are partly hidden. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: use mar=c(5, 6, 4, 2) in the setting of par, so par to include par(mar=c(5, 6, 4, 2))

Comment: Thanks! In case I want to increase space between y label and y axis, what should I do?

Comment: use mgp in par, so mar=c(5, 7, 4, 2),mgp=c(4,1,0)